# break and continue in for loop in php

Tags: php

I am running a php for loop which starts with 14

```
for($p = 14; $p<$num_parts; $p++)
```

I want is after every 14 count loop stops then again continue with next 14 in next page.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$i = 14;
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loopindex'])) {
  $i = $_SESSION['loopindex'];;
} 

for($p = $i; $p<$num_parts; $p++){
 //do stuff
 if($p % 14 == 0 && $p > 14){
 $_SESSION['loopindex'] = $p;
 break;
 }
}
```

Dont forget to unset or reset your session to 14 when you are done (loop ends) like this:

```
unset($_SESSION['loopindex']);//unset
```

or

```
$_SESSION['loopindex'] = 14;//reset
```

Answer (score -2):

for sloving this problem it's not necessary to use `break` or `continue` instructions
you can use a condition inside your loop , where you will test if the variable p is divisble by 14
like in this pseudocode

```
if(p%14 == 0 && p!=14)
```

Comment: Modulo is correct but then he wants to break the loop and continue with it in the next page, thus, reserving current loop status. This should be done by session. check my answer.